# serving web app and python using nginx on remote server

Tags: post, nginx, flask, get

Setup:
1> Web GUI using Angular JS hoasted in tomcat server and Python app using Flask is running on an AWS server.
2> I am working in a secure server hence am unable to access AWS directly.
3> I have setup NGINX to access GUI app from my local secured network. GUI app is running on awsserver:9506/appName
4> Flask app is running in AWS server hosted on 127.0.0.1:5000. This app has 2 uri's cross and accross:
127.0.0.1:5000/cross
127.0.0.1:5000/accross

Now in my GUI after NGINX setup i am able to access it using domain name and without port:
doman.name/appName

Now when i try to use it send a request to server my url changes to:
doman.name/cross. I did the changes in NGINX config and am able to access it but am not able to get a response back. Please find below my NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.name;
    root /home/Tomcat/webapps/appName;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hostIP:9505/;                 #runs the tomcat home page
    }

    location /appName/ {
        proxy_pass http://hostIP:9505/appName;          #runs the application home page
    }

    location /cross/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/cross;         #hits the python flask app and am trying to send post
    }
}
```

Also what i noticed is that my POST request is being converted to GET at the server by NGINX

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistent with your use of the trailing `/`. With the `proxy_pass` statement (as with `alias`) `nginx` performs text substitution to form the rewritten URI.

Is the URI of the API `/cross` or `/cross/`? POST is converted to GET when the server is forced to perform a redirect (for example, to append a `/`).

Specifying the same URI on the `location` and `proxy_pass` is unnecessary as no changes are made.

If the `hostIP` in your first two `location` blocks is the same, and assuming that the missing trailing `/` is accidental, they can be combined into a single `location` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://hostIP:9505;
}
location /cross {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

Comment: Thank you so very much. The whole issue was the trailing forward slash. It is finally working like a charm. As you mentioned the forward slash was changing my POST to GET. Much obliged :)